# Плагин для Sublime Text

Tags: html, вёрстка, css, sublime-text

Есть ли для Sublime Text плагин для переноса из уже имеющегося HTML, структуры классов в CSS, например, вот есть такая структура:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link"></a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link"></a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link"></a></li>
</ul>
```

А после выделения и нажатия хоткея, в CSS, скажем, в конец файла вставляется следующее:

```
.menu {

}
.menu__item {

    }
    .menu__link {

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, есть такой плагин, CSS Primer - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Primer

Answer (score 0):

Плагин не обнаружил, но могу порекомендовать сервисы http://extractcss.com/ + http://css2less.cc/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки =)

Answer (score 0):

Плагин называется Tag, посмотри даже на ютубе есть видео на русском по нему
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Tag